# jQuery RemoveAttr and IE8 - Only effective after another component has focus

Tags: jquery

I use the following code to hide 1-4 rows of a table when a checkbox is selected:

```
    for(i = 1; i < 4; i++){
      $(tbProf.rows[i]).attr('style','display:none');

      // same problem with
      // $(tbProf.rows[i]).hide();
    }
```

and reverse when its unticked:

```
    for(i = 1; i < 4; i++){
      $(tbProf.rows[i]).removeAttr('style');

      // same problem with 
      // $(tbProf.rows[i]).show();

    }
```

It works perfectly fine in Chrome/Firefox:

In IE7/8 however the rows only hide/show after i click somewhere(anywhere) in the form after which the style is applied! Can anyone suggest a workaround for IE8? [ i have to support IE8 :(  ]

Comment: can you just use .css('display', 'none'), .css('display', 'table-row');?

Comment: it has same effect, it only gets applied only after i click somewhere in the form and not immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood the problem, but what you need to do? Show and hide these rows?
Why not use show() and hide() functions?

**Edit 1:**

So, try using:

```
$(tbProf.rows[i]).hide();
```

and

```
$(tbProf.rows[i]).show();
```

**Edit 2:**

A better example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FCuJx/) (using the [:lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector). May be usefull for you.

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: thanks for reply, see updated Q. show/hide has the same problem in IE7/8

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't have IE 7 and 8 installed here to help you more. I trying to find the known issues with IE, but I just find this: http://docs.jquery.com/Known_Issues. What version of jQuery are you using?